# Create a batch file that reads all the text files contained in current directory

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

The essence of the task in the description, so far I have a code reading the file. But the cycle can not be put into a loop in batch

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (text1.txt) do echo %%x

PAUSE
```

Comment: Reading means just enumerating or read the file contents?

Comment: @LotPings Contents

Comment: Replace Echo with Type in @Compos batch. Or do you want to process line by line of each file? That can be achieved with a second stacked for.

Comment: @LotPings I just need to display their content on the screen

Comment: Then simply use `Type *.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than that:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%A IN (*.txt) DO ECHO %%A
PAUSE
```

**Edit**

To satisfy your more clear requirement then just use this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
TYPE *.txt
PAUSE
```

Comment: I need to display the contents of the files, not their name

Answer (score 0):

Thank **CuprumBur** for answer from ru.stackoverflow.com

```
@echo off
chcp 1251
for  %%f in (*.txt) do (
type %%f
echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: You can use `type *.txt` if you don't mind the filenames printed before the content. Also, it's bad form to permanently change the user's console codepage. You should save the previous codepage and restore it on exit.